# Matrix representation and CX gate

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I am having hard time figuring out how the CX (controlled-NOT) gate is represented in the matrix representation.

I understood that tensor product and the identity matrix are the keys, and I understood how the matrix representation works for single-qubit matrices. For example, if we have a circuit with a quantum register `q` composed of 3 qubits, the operation `X q[1]` has the matrix representation <sup>1</sup>
$$I_2 \otimes X \otimes I_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Obviously, I am aware of the matrix representation of the CX gate:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Taking back our quantum register `q`, applying `CX` to the second (control) and third register (target) (`CX q[1], q[2]`) gives us the matrix representation <sup>2</sup>
$$I_2 \otimes CX = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The problem comes when we try to apply the `CX` gate to other pairs of qubits:

1. I suspect the matrix representation of `CX q[2], q[1]` (applying a `CX` gate with the third qubit of the system as control and the second qubit of the system as target) to be $I_2 \otimes CX^r$ where $$CX^r = \begin{pmatrix}
   0&1&0&0\\
   1&0&0&0\\
   0&0&1&0\\
   0&0&0&1\\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   but I am not sure.
2. I really don't know how `CX q[0], q[2]` (applying a `CX` gate with the first qubit of the system as control and the third qubit of the system as target) would be represented.

**To summarise**, my question is "how does the `CX` (or more generally multi-qubit gates) is represented as a matrix when there are more than 2 qubits in the system?".

<sup>1</sup> Computed with Python and numpy:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
ID2 = np.identity(2)
print(np.kron(np.kron(ID2, X), X))
```

<sup>2</sup> Computed with Python and numpy:

```
import numpy as np
CX = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
ID2 = np.identity(2)
print(np.kron(ID2, CX))
```

Comment: can you spell out in words what you mean by `CX q[0], q[2]` and the likes? I'm not familiar with Q# notation (or whatever notation that is)

Comment: I edited my question! Tell me if it is not enough.

Comment: You can conjugate by the appropriate swaps. Figure out what permutation you need to get the indices as you already had them and break that into swaps.

Comment: Most of the answer to your question can be found on this related question: "[How to derive the CNOT matrix for a 3-qbit system where the control & target qbits are not adjacent?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4252/124)"

Comment: You are right, I did poorly my prior research... But the answer of glS is complementary. You explain very well for the 3-qubit case, @glS generalise this to any number of qubits.

Comment: @Nelimee: No problem, though I do also describe how this extends to many qubits --- I just don't write any examples of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to get it via braket notation.

Consider the general case of $n$ qubits. The representation of a CNOT between the last two qubits (last qubit being the target) is easily seen to be:
$$\newcommand{\ketbra}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle\!\langle#1\rvert}
CX_{n-1\to n}= I_{2^{n-2}}\otimes\big(\ketbra0\otimes I_2+\ketbra1\otimes X\big),$$
that is, in matrix notation, the resulting of tensoring the identity over the first $n-2$ qubits with the usual CNOT matrix.

What if the CNOT acts instead between the $i$-th and $j$-th qubits?
The braket representation does not change significantly, we just need to change the order of the terms so that it becomes a bit uglier$^1$:
\begin{align}
CX_{i\to j} &=
I_{2^{i-1}}\otimes\ketbra0\otimes I_{2^{j-i-1}}\otimes I\otimes I_{2^{n-j}} \\
&+ I_{2^{i-1}}\otimes\ketbra1\otimes I_{2^{j-i-1}}\otimes X\otimes I_{2^{n-j}}.
\end{align}
To build up the typical matrix representation you then just compute the Kronecker product of these terms.

For example, if $n=3$, the control is the third qubit and the target is the first second qubit, you have
$$CX_{3\to 2}=I\otimes I\otimes\ketbra0+I\otimes X\otimes \ketbra1.$$

---

$^1$ Note that the way I've written it, this representation only works for $i<j$, but I'm sure you can easily see what it becomes when $i>j$.