What is the action of $CCZ$ on $X \times I \times I$?
Confused about the action of the $CCZ$ gate on Pauli operators:
I understand the action of the $CZ$ gate: $$CZ: XI \rightarrow XX$$ $$CZ: IX \rightarrow IX$$ $$CZ: ZI \rightarrow ZI$$ $$CZ: IZ \rightarrow IZ$$ I have verified this by means of matrix multiplication. However, I then get confused when I see:
$$CCZ: XII \rightarrow X(CZ)$$ $$CCZ: ZII \rightarrow ZII$$
(similar for acting on $X_{2}$, $X_{3}$, $Z_{2}$, $Z_{3}$).
I just don't understand the action of $CCZ$ on $XII$. Specifically, I don't understand the notation $X(CZ)$. At first I thought it was matrix multiplication but $X$ is $2 \times 2$ and $CZ$ is $4 \times 4$.
If anybody could help me understand what $X(CZ)$ is, that would be very helpful!

I think the parentheses in $X(CZ)$ just tell you that this is a tensor product of two gates, where the first is the $X$ gate (2x2 matrix) and the second the $CZ$ gate (4x4 matrix) in contrast to being the tensor product of three gates ($X$, $C$ and $Z$) as in the case of $ZII$ ($Z$, $I$ and $I$).

$CCZ$ will map $X_iI_jI_k$ to $(X_iI_jI_k)(CZ_{j,k})$ by conjugation where the parenthesis indicates the regular product (i.e. gate chaining) and $CZ_{j,k}$ is the $CZ$ operator between qubit $j$ and $k$ (seen as an operator on three qubits).
This notation is confusing if you do not include indices: $I_1X_2I_3$ is mapped to $(I_1X_2I_3)(CZ_{1,3})$, which is not intuitively understood from $X(CZ)$ reading from left to right, expecting the left most operator to act on the first qubit.
The action of $CCZ$ is more complex than the one of $CZ$ because they do not belong to the same class of the Clifford hierarchy (see this question where its precise definition appears). $CZ$ is a Clifford gate (belonging to the first class) and therefore maps Pauli operators to Pauli operators. $CCZ$ belongs to the second class: it maps Pauli operators to elements of the first class of the hierarchy, here a product between a Pauli operator ($X$) and a non-Pauli operator (the $CZ$ gate).

In terms of the matrix representation. $CCZ =diag(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1)$. Then $CZ_{1,2}=diag(1,1,0,1,-1,0)$. $CZ_{2,3}=diag(0,1,1,0,1,-1)$ and $CZ_{1,3}=diag(1,0,1,1,0,-1)$? Is this correct? So then CCZ will map $IXI$ to $X_{2} \otimes CZ_{1,3}$, which is a $24 \otimes 24$ matrix? Or does matrix representation not really work here?....I think I've got something wrong along the way

$CZ_{1,2}$ might not be as clear as a notation as I thought. By $X_2 \otimes CZ_{1,3}$ I meant the operator which acts as $X$ on qubit 2 and as $CZ$ on qubits 1 and 3 (i.e. a $8\times 8$ matrix). diag(1,1,0,1,-1,0) doesn't make sense as an operator, it is not of size $2^i \times 2^i$. It is probably more rigorous to say that $IXI$ is mapped to $X_2$ followed by a $CZ$ between qubits 1 and 3 and to not try to express it as a tensor product. I will edit my answer.

Okay, thank you! Yes, I had thought that maybe $CZ1,3$ could be expressed as $I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0| + Z \otimes |2 \rangle \langle 2|$ (hence the $diag(1,1,0,1,-1,0)$) because I had seen CZ1,2 expressed as $I \otimes |0\rangle \langle0| + Z \otimes |1 \rangle \langle 1| $ but obviously this is not the case!

@am567 You can have a look at this question to better grasp controlled operations in a system with more than two qubits: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/how-to-derive-the-cnot-matrix-for-a-3-qubit-system-where-the-control-target-qu

CCZ is defined by
$$
CCZ \vert{x_1,x_2,x_3} \rangle = \vert x_1, x_2 \rangle Z^{x_1\cdot x_2} \vert{x_3}\rangle = (-1)^{x_1 x_2 x_3} \vert{x_1,x_2,x_3} \rangle
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
(CCZ)(XII)(CCZ)\vert{x_1,x_2,x_3}\rangle  =  (-1)^{x_1 x_2 x_3} CCZ\vert{1 \oplus x_1,x_2, x_3} \rangle = (-1)^{x_1 x_2 x_3} (-1)^{(1 \oplus x_1) x_2 x_3}  \vert 1 \oplus x_1,x_2, x_3\rangle
\end{align}
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
 ()\vert{x_1,x_2,x_3} \rangle = \vert{1 \oplus x_1} \rangle \vert {x_2}\rangle Z^{x_2} \vert{x_3} \rangle = (-1)^{x_2 \oplus x_3}  \vert 1 \oplus x_1,x_2, x_3\rangle. 
\end{align} 
These to expressions are the same because exactly one of $x_1$ and $1 \oplus x_1$ equals 1.
